# Bash scripting for arithmetic expression

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
x=10
echo x=$x
z=20
echo z=$z
y= expr $x + $z
echo y=$y
```

I want output like :

```
x=10
z=20
y=30
```

but it gives error like:

```
x=10
z=20
30
y=
```

Comment: `y=$(expr $x + $z)` instead of `y= expr $x + $z`

Comment: `y=\`expr $x + $z\` ` also works, looking for "Command Substitution in bash", is better Inian's solution way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do **`NOT`** use the outdated construct `expr`, use the arithmetic operator `$(())` for `POSIX` compliant arithmetic in `bash`

```
y=$((x + z))
echo "y=$y"
```

Comment: `$((...))` is not just standard, but it performs the arithmetic in the current process, rather than starting a new process to run `expr`.

Comment: Additionally, you could replace `y=$((x + z))` with `((y = x + z))` or simply `y=x+z` if you declare x, y and z as integers prior with `declare -i x y z`